# How to run .pro file in exelis IDL

Tags: idl-programming-language

I'm trying to run a .pro file on IDL, I opened the file in IDL, but I cannot input anything at the console[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqi5O.png)
I'm using IDL on ubuntu.

Is it because the environment isn't set up well? I also try to click the 'compile&run', it is not responding.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the end of the code, but assuming there is an `end` at the end of the code, you should be able to run your code with:;

```
IDL> .run mdot
```

Also, be careful, your file has not been saved.

Comment: Thank u so much